# How do you get all seven premium knives?

Tags: battlefield-4

On the premium calendar it says you get five knives, but there are seven knives marked as premium content on battlelog. Do you get the other two randomly by opening battlepacks while being a premium member, or is there some other way to acquire them?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what it is you're trying to ask here.

Comment: so on the calender it shows 5 knives while in unlocks it shows 7 knives for premium members. 5 are for the knife battlepacks but how do you get the other 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the other premium knives via battle packs.

As of posting this (14.04.2014) there are only 2 premium knives via the calendar, but I have 3 (Trench, Seal and Carbon Fiber). 2 from calendar and 1 from a battle pack.
[image]